Get end date over a group from startdate of the previous group
I have the following TSQL query
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        [id],
        residentId,
        LoadDateTime AS StartDate,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LoadDateTime DESC) AS Run
    FROM 
        [ResManPStage].[Residencies] WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE  
        residentId IN (4719)
) 
SELECT DISTINCT 
    id, residentId, StartDate, Run
FROM
    cte

This query returns the following data:



id
residentId
StartDate
Run




4853
4719
2024-06-04 04:41:25.113
1


4853
4719
2024-06-04 04:41:25.113
1


4853
4719
2024-06-04 04:41:25.113
1


4853
4719
2024-06-04 04:28:26.493
2


4853
4719
2024-06-04 04:28:26.493
2


4853
4719
2024-06-04 04:28:26.493
2



I want the following output



id
residentId
StartDate
Run
EndDate




4853
4719
2024-06-04 04:41:25.113
1
NULL


4853
4719
2024-06-04 04:41:25.113
1
NULL


4853
4719
2024-06-04 04:41:25.113
1
NULL


4853
4719
2024-06-04 04:28:26.493
2
2024-06-04 04:41:25.113


4853
4719
2024-06-04 04:28:26.493
2
2024-06-04 04:41:25.113


4853
4719
2024-06-04 04:28:26.493
2
2024-06-04 04:41:25.113



I want to make the StartDate of current group as the EndDate of the previous group. There are several groups that are a combination of ID, RUN and StartDate.
I am able to do this across single rows using LAG and/or LEAD function but not able to do when there are more than 1 row in a group.

Don't use WITH (NOLOCK). There are effectively zero legitimate reasons for using it today.

"I want to make the StartDate of current group as the EndDate of previous group" - use another CTE to reduce your data down to a single row for each group and use LAG() with that, JOIN'd with your current CTE results.

'I want to make the StartDate of current group as the EndDate of previous group' - is this the wrong way round ? looks like from your example enddate of current group as the startdate of previous group'

We can try creating a CTE which computes the end dates using the LEAD() window function.  Then join this CTE to your original table to bring in the end dates.
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, LoadDateTime,
           LEAD(LoadDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY LoadDateTime) LeadLoadDateTime
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, LoadDateTime FROM [ResManPStage].[Residencies]) t
)

SELECT t1.id, t1.residentId, t1.LoadDateTime AS StartDate,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY LoadDateTime DESC) AS Run,
       t2.LeadLoadDateTime AS EndDate
FROM [ResManPStage].[Residencies] t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id AND
       t2.LoadDateTime = t1.LoadDateTime
ORDER BY t1.id, t1.LoadDateTime DESC;

